# INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a mysql table named `company_profile`. It may have only one record. So I tried to insert and update data of the table using `INSERT.... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query.

This is how I tried it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO company_profile ( 
                      company_name
                    , tel
                    , mobile
                    , fax
                    , email
                 ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                      company_name= VALUES(company_name)
                    , tel         = VALUES(tel)
                    , mobile      = VALUES(mobile)
                    , fax         = VALUES(fax)
                    , email       = VALUES(email)";                

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $company_name
                         , $telephone
                         , $mobile
                         , $fax
                         , $email
                        );
$stmt->execute();
```

My problem is when I updating the data, it always inserting a new record into my table.

Can anybody tell me what would be the problem of this?

My table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company_profile (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    company_name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
    tel VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    mobile VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,    
    fax VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,   
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How can Mysql know that the value you insert is not a duplicate? You primary key is `id` and you're not passing it to your query.

Comment: Your only unique key is the `id` -> `PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE KEY (id)`. So which column should invoke the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is redundant to define a key as being both `unique` and `primary key`.  Just define `id` to be primary key.

Then, you need a unique constraint/index on the columns used for duplication (the two are functionally equivalent for this purpose).  I am guessing uniqueness is based on the company name:

```
create unique index unq_company_profile_company_name on company_profile(company_name);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. One question, can we define this `unique constraint/index` within `create table` ?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the docs for [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) syntax. You already have `UNIQUE KEY(columns...)` in your table structure. Just change `UNIQUE KEY (id)` to `UNIQUE KEY (company_name)`. In Gordon's example, he names the constraint but if you choose not too, a name is auto-generated.